# jinja2 filesystemloader load all subdirectories

Tags: python, jinja2

I currently have templates in multiple different sub directories and I would like to load all of the templates in jinja2. It appears that just pointing the FileSystemLoader directory at the top of the tree doesn't pick up anything in the sub folders.

Is there a way to get jinja2 to load all of the sub directories (just a single level down is ok but the whole tree would be preferable)?

So far I've managed to do this with a choice loader:

```
sub_dirs = [os.path.join(template_file_root,dirname) for dirname in os.listdir(template_file_root) 
\ if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(template_file_root, dirname))]

jinja_dirs = [ jinja2.FileSystemLoader(dirname) for dirname in sub_dirs ]

template_env = jinja2.Environment (loader = jinja2.ChoiceLoader(jinja_dirs))
```

However this seems a little hacky. Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 35):

Jinja does take the subfolders into account, but templates must be referenced with paths relative to the root folder.

If we have mydir/foo/bar.html, this works:

```
template_env = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader('mydir'))
template_env.get_template('foo/bar.html')
```

Comment: I have the same problem OP may have been trying to solve when a template has an `import` (or presumably `extends`) that is relative to itself.

Comment: they should have some documentation about this, as this is not evident !